# I keep getting keyError: "data" Python

Tags: python, json, url

Ok.. I've actually tried so hard to figure this out by myself, but I just can't seem to figure it out.

I'm trying to access a json file, and printing out some stuff that I wanted.

The url I'm trying to access is this:
https://www.reddit.com/user/clockwork8.json

So here's the deal

I have right now:

```
import urllib, json, unicodedata

username1 = raw_input('Username: ')
url1 = "https://www.reddit.com/user/clockwork8"
response = urllib.urlopen(url1)
data = json.loads(response.read())
```

at the top of the code, and I tried the following two options:

```
for number in data["data"]["children"]:
    for fordata in data["data"]["children"][number]:
        if fordata == "data":
            for key in data["data"]["children"][post][fordata]:
                if key == "score":
                    print data["data"]["children"][post]["data"][key].encode('ascii')
                if key == "link_url":
                    print data["data"]["children"][post]["data"][key].encode('ascii')
```

which gives me this error:

```
    for fordata in data["data"]["children"][number]:
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not dict
```

So I tried this:

```
for a in range(len(data['data']['children'])):
    print data['data']['children'][a]['data']['score'].encode('ascii')
```

and now it gives me this error:

```
    for a in range(len(data['data']['children'])):
KeyError: 'data'
```

Any idea what the problem is..?

Comment: Which objects in `data` do you want? Using your code I'm getting `25` results

Comment: Maybe you want `print [d['data']['score'] for d in data['data']['children']]` ? Gives 25 `scores`: [3,
 1,
 2,
 1,
 0,
 2,
 1,
 0,
 -3,
 9,
 1,
 3,
 2,
 2,
 4,
 2,
 1,
 2,
 16,
 -1,
 58,
 3,
 1,
 0,
 -18]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you want all the scores from that `json` object.

Each object in `data['data']['children']` has a `data` key, so we need to call `data` on each them. Furthermore, to get each of those `data`'s `'score'` value, we need to call its `[data][score]`:

Using a `for`-loop like you were:

```
for d in data['data']['children']:
    print d['data']['score']
```

will print each `'score'` one at a time, or you can get all the `'scores'` in a list using python's list comprehension syntax which gives us a one-liner:

```
scores = [d['data']['score'] for d in data['data']['children']]
```

`scores` now contains a list of 25 values:

```
[3, 1, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0, -3, 9, 1, 3, 2, 2, 4, 2, 1, 2, 16, -1, 58, 3, 1, 0, -18]
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I really don't know if it's a problem with my computer, but I copied your code EXACTLy the same, with the topbit of my code containing import and the url, but there's STILL an error message...     scores = [d['data']['score'] for d in data['data']['children']]
KeyError: 'data'

Comment: Oh, sorry, yes you're right... you need to add `.json` to the url: `url1 = "https://www.reddit.com/user/clockwork8.json"`; and use the `json.load` method, not `loads`: `data = json.load(response)`

Comment: Ok Thanks so much!! could you please explain what the format of your code was..? is it iterating through every instance of ['data']['score'] in data['data']['children']?

Comment: Yes, that's right! `data['data']['children']` returns 25 objects that each *ALSO* have a `data` key (that's what was confusing me). So the format `d in data['data']['children']` assigns each of the 25 results to `d`, which then you iterate over each instance, as you said, calling their `['data']['score']`

Comment: I see... so the d in front of `d['data']['score']` is each dictionary within `data['data']['children']`, right? That's such a clean way to write code! Where can I learn more about writing it in a format like that?

Comment: Exactly, yep you got the idea. The format I wrote it in is python's infamous [list comprehension](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk) syntax. That link explains it a lot better than I ever could. It's really just a glorified couple of `for` loops in a one-liner. You could write the same thing, like you were doing in nested-for loops, but as you said, that format is easier to read. Check out any reference on "list comprehensions", here's another good one: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/python/196/comprehensions/737/list-comprehensions#t=201703170245203875306

Comment: ^^ I added more info for you. Very glad it helped you! :) Cheers!